# Ruby on Rails, controller doesn't seem to be linking to view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my `index.html.erb` file, this lot of code works:

```
<% if Restaurant.all.any? %>
  <% Restaurant.all.each do |restaurant| %>
    <h2><%= restaurant.name %></h2>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <h1>No restaurants yet!</h1>
<% end %>

<a href='#'>Add a restaurant</a>
```

However, when I change the controller to this:

```
 class RestaurantsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @restaurants = Restaurant.all
   end
 end
```

and the `index.html.erb` file to this:

```
<% if @restaurants.any? %>
  <% @restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
    <h2><%= restaurant.name %></h2>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <h1>No restaurants yet!</h1>
<% end %>

<a href='#'>Add a restaurant</a>
```

all of the tests which passed, now fail because of that change, and I can't for the life of me work out why they are not working. The error message when running the tests is:

```
 Failure/Error: visit '/restaurants'
 ActionView::Template::Error:
   undefined method `any?' for nil:NilClass
```

My routes.rb file is as follows:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :restaurants
end
```

Comment: show me you routes file.

Comment: did you do `rake db:create && rake db:migrate`

Comment: problem with "@restaurants" objects. Please check why value of @restaurants is nil.

Comment: How are you hitting the route which is causing the issue ? From tests ?

Comment: Yeah, I did rake db:create && rake db:migrate

Comment: @olucas92, instead of `if @restaurants.any?` please try it out with `unless @restaurants.blank?`, i hope this will work

Comment: try <% if @restaurants && @restaurants.any? %>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually the problem is that your index is called directly without going to controller. So earlier your `"Restaurant.all"` works correctly but now atfer new changes `@restuanants` is null and you applied `null.any?`. It gives error.
try

```
 <% if @restaurants && @restaurants.any? %>
```

or

```
<% unless @restaurants.blank? %>
```

Comment: How you got it ? How was he trying ?

Comment: Because if the request comes from controller then Restaurant.all returns blank array. [].any? runs correctly.

Comment: using .blank? is always a good practice because it checks for nil and empty both

Comment: @SachinR, I think instead of checking two condition `@restaurants && @restaurants.any?` its better if we will use `@restaurants.blank?`

Answer (score 1):

Try this I hope this will help

In **index.html.erb**

```
<% unless @restaurants.blank? %>
  <% @restaurants.each do |restaurant| %>
    <h2><%= restaurant.name %></h2>
  <% end %>
<% else %>
  <h1>No restaurants yet!</h1>
<% end %>

<a href='#'>Add a restaurant</a>
```